# Vue JS Transition not working Nuxt JS Project

Tags: css, vue.js, animation, nuxt.js

This animation working Vue JS project and not working Nuxt JS Project.
What could be wrong with my code?

My animation code is like this.

```
<transition name="fade">
  <div :class="index === 0 ? 'ua-border-radius-top-24' : index === thisArray.length - 1 ? 'ua-border-radius-bottom-24 mt-2' : 'mt-2'" class="ua-h-79-px p-2 shadow-sm ua-bg-color-white ua-hover-pointer">
     <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-2 col-lg-3 ua-border-right-theme-blue ua-flex-full-align ua-h-65-px">
           <img class="img-fluid" :src="thisType === 'notice' ? '/notice-icon-2.svg' : ''" alt="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-10 col-lg-9">
           <div class="ua-flex-vertical ua-h-65-px">
             <div>
               <a class="ua-text-size-12 ua-text-color-theme-blue">{{$moment(item.createdAt).format('DD.MM.YYYY') }}</a>
             </div>
             <div>
               <a class="d-block d-lg-none d-xl-block ua-text-size-12 ua-text-color-dark">{{item.title.length >= 50 ? `${item.title.substring(0, 50)}...` : item.title}}</a>
               <a class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none ua-text-size-12 ua-text-color-dark">{{item.title.length >= 40 ? `${item.title.substring(0, 38)}...` : item.title}}</a>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </transition>
```

My style codes are as follows.

```
.fade-enter {
  color: red;
  transform: translateY(20px);
}

.fade-enter-active {
  transition: transform .3s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0), color .5s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0);
}

.fade-leave-active {
  transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0), color 1s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0);
}

.fade-leave-to {
  transform: translateX(100px);
  color: cyan;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a transition key to your component should fix the problem.

export default {
transition: 'fade'
}

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/transitions/